# MYSQL query NOW() adjusted to a specific timezone

Tags: mysql

my query is

```
 SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE times >= DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/New_York'), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE )
```

which doesn't work.

values stored in my DB are 5 hours forward, but I'm in NY, so I need to find rows that are within 60 minutes of my timezone

```
item 1 | 2018-01-10 00:09:03
item 2 | 2018-01-10 00:05:03
item 3 | 2018-01-10 00:04:03
item 4 | 2018-01-10 00:02:03
```

but currently in NY is 2018-01-10 19:11:03

so how do i select rows within 60 minutes based on -5hrs timezone?

Comment: You want to have a value that matchs your timezone? Cuse to me it seams like you are converting the time zone and add an interval on it.

Comment: @MadeInDreams i'm storing values that are in London timezone, but when I query to find the last 5 minutes rows I don't get the expected results...because the time forward...so i cant find anything in the last 5 minutes...

Comment: How long ago are your result from? or from now?

Comment: Try adding the time diffrence manualy instead of a timezone.
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET'); They are passing 2 timezone to the function.

Comment: you want results that are within 1 hour from your actual time. And your query is asking for anything greater or equal then your time converted to GMT-5 + 1. So you should get anything grater than 23h11 today. Kind of hard to tell cuse all your result are after that time.